# How to batch rename embedded (linked) textures in a scene?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, file-format, file-browser

is there a way to batch rename all textures that are used by the all objects in a given scene? Background of this question is as follows:

I'm creating a set of models that all will be textured (diff, roughness, normal), and all textures will be of 4k size.
After creation, i want to have a copy of the 4K textures in 2k size. Therefore, i export all textures by using "File" --> "External data" --> "Unpack all into files". Then, i use irfan view to batch resize and rename all textures, giving them the suffix "_2k". But when i re-link the files, the file connection in the shader nodes is lost. They need to be re-linked manually. Doing this manually is ok for a small amount of textures, but this time i will have about 100 textures.

So, how can i achieve to rename all textures without loosing the connection to the shader nodes? Some advice will be very helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question was answered at blenderartists. See the solution with a phyton script here:

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?441069-How-to-batch-rename-embedded-(linked)-textures-in-a-scene

Thanks to the users Photox and MartinZ for help!